# mysql aes_encrypt returns strings with single quote and/or double quotes

Tags: mysql, aes, quote

MySql aes_encrypt function returns strings with single quote and/or double quotes, it results in error while storing the encrypted string in mysql table. How to handle it. Please help.

Note: Using addslashes or mysql_real_escape_string returns wrong decrypt values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you calling `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape MySQL function result? use `AES_ENCRYPT` in your INSERT/UDPATE statement.

Comment: Also, note that `AES_ENCRYPT()` does not return a "string."  It returns binary data, and must be stored in a column with a binary (not character) data type.